# Flutter provider getting old category list after visit new category

Tags: flutter, flutter-3.0

I'm trying to display products list after click on category, problem is after click on category if I go category details page, then If I back to list page then click another category page then it first displaying old category data then new category data. My category details page looks like

```
class _CategoryDetailsScreenState extends State<CategoryDetailsScreen> {
     late List  _product;

    @override
    void initState() {
        //ModalRoute not work in init state without future delayed
     Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) 
     {
        var _args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as CategoryDetailsScreenArgs;
        Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context,listen:false).fetchAndSetCatProducts(catid: _args.id, page: page);
     }
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        _product.clear();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){

        _product =  Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context).products;

        return Scaffold(
              body: _product.isEmpty? widget One : Product Widget
        )

    }

}
```

Problem in video : https://youtube.com/shorts/ETdz37FkA-0

I have _product!.clear() in disposed method , then why still getting old than new values ?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you should clear the products item inside the provider, something like

```
        Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context,listen:false).clearProduct();
```

where you set the product in the state like a new initial product